# Math Question that came up in my exam Series Question

Tags: calculus

So I am a High School Student and I take advanced Mathematics but this was in the core paper. I was told I was not allowed to use anything that we haven't been taught in core(Calculus)

This is the question

$x_0$ (row 1): 2

$x_1$ (row 2): 6; 10

$x_2$ (row 3): 14; 18; 22

$x_3$ (row 4): 26; 30; 34; 38

$x_4$ (row 5): 32....

What is the sum of the numbers(ie 100 + 101 = 201) in the 8th row.

I think the row is

$$x_{n+1} = x_n + 4 $$
where $x_0 = 2 $

I can do this question using calculus

My method:

$r= a.row.you.want - 1$

$g = \frac{(r^2)}{2} + \frac{(r)}{2}$

$$\sum_{n=g}^{g+r} 4n+2$$

$r = 7$

$g = \frac{(7^2)}{2} + \frac{(7)}{2}$
$;g = 28$

$$\sum_{n=28}^{35} 4n+2 =1024$$

But since it was in core there must be a function that can do this without the need for sigma.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How is a row generated? Is there anz rule for how to get from, say, row $i$ to row $i+1$?

Comment: Added more info

Comment: It's still unclear. What is $x_n$, exactly, and how is it connected to the rows?

Comment: Also, what does the question ask for? You say the "sum of the digits". Does that mean we have to take the digits of the numbers in the row? For example, if the row is $101, 104$, is the sum of the digits $1+0+1+1+0+4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative method.

Firstly, the numbers $2,6,10,14,...$ form an arithmetic progression $a_n$ with $a_1=2,d=4$.

Secondly, notice the correspondence between the row number and the number of terms, so the row $8$ will have $8$ terms.

Thirdly, notice the first terms in each row: $a_1,a_2,a_4,a_7,a_{11},a_{16},a_{22},a_{29}$...

Hence, you add the row $8$ terms:
$$a_{29}+a_{30}+\cdots +a_{36}=\frac{a_{29}+a_{36}}{2}\cdot 8=\frac{a_1+28d+a_1+35d}{2}\cdot 8=1024.$$